# Node - Override function in all files except one

Tags: node.js, overriding, console.log

I've been looking around at somehow disabling console.log in my application while running unit tests, and I found answers that say you can override the console.log like this:

```
console.log = function(){};
```

I tried putting this in app.js, and it overrides console.log when I'm running the app, but not when running unit tests, so I tried adding it the to test file, but then it overrides mocha / chai's console.log, and I get a blank screen.

Is there a way to override the console.log in all files except the one running?

Answer (score 0):

What you would probably want to do instead is use a logging library like Loggly or Bunyan. With these you pass the message you want to log to the client and then you can output those logs based on the environment you are in. In your case you want to log during production but not during testing (kindof odd, but whatever). So you would set process.NODE_ENV to dev or prod accordingly and the logger would take care of the logging for you. [Here's an overview of some loggers](https://www.loggly.com/blog/three-node-js-libraries-which-make-sophisticated-logging-simplers/).